# How can I make VS Code display text like 'is_foo' as 'foo?'

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to display methods starting with `is_` like `is_foo` as `foo?`. How can that be done? For methods like `is_object`, `is_empty` etc.

The example expression config may look something like:

```
ugly:   /[^a-z]is_(.+)[^a-z]/
pretty: "$1?"
```

P.S. There're some extensions that can do something similar, but not quite that, they can't do replacements with the captures.

Comment: huh... and what would you want / expect to happen if you want to edit the part of the actual text that is not displayed ("`is_`")?

Answer (score -1):

Does this satisfy your needs?:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=siegebell.prettify-symbols-mode

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but I can't figure out how to do substitution, as far as I understand it only can substitute expression with fixed pretty symbols.

Comment: You could add something like below to the settings.json. You would have to add to it for each variation of is_whatever, but it would probably better than looking at it ugly!

`
{
            "language": "python",
            "substitutions": [
                {
                    "ugly": "is_some",
                    "pretty": "some?",
                },
                {
                    "ugly": "is_object",
                    "pretty": "object?"
                }
            ]
        },
`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).